# What are these dishes looking at?

Tags: iss, communication, antenna

In this [CSA video](https://youtu.be/IZHw4UKFiHQ) CSA Astronaut Chris Hadfield describes the attitude control of the ISS and its importance for things like communication with Earth.

At `00:30` here is about a 2 second vignette of these four identical fixed dish antennas all apparently pointing in the same direction -- in the general direction of the Sun, which would be south if this is in North America.

Are these used to communicate or control the ISS, or is this just commercial stock footage of a cable tv station?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's stock footage. Here's the source: https://www.shutterstock.com/video/clip-3547922-stock-footage-satellite.html?src=search/j9qjEB4D-XcqsNoqfQWZrA:1:4/gg

Comment: OK, so much for my well-researched questions (blush).

Comment: I didn't downvote your question. That was someone else. That said, all I had to do was to do a google reverse image search on the image you yourself used in the question. Amusingly, google's best guess for that image is "satellites on the ground."

Comment: Choice of stock footage may have been done in deference to the locations of the real ground stations. However, while the two in White Sands may not be so YouTube friendly, one can drive past the one in Guam and catch a glimpse, in reality or in google maps: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZiWJ.jpg

Comment: Yeah, the ones at White Sands aren't very photo friendly.  As you drive down the road toward them, there are multiple "RESTRICTED FACILITY, AUTHORIZED PERSONNEL ONLY" and "PHOTOGRAPHY STRICTLY PROHIBITED" signs starting about five miles from where the dishes actually are.

Comment: The ground stations used to communicate with the ISS are all in Russia. The US side uses the TDRSS.

Comment: Google Maps has them https://www.google.com/maps/place/White+Sands+Second+TDRSS+Ground+Terminal/@32.5430115,-106.6139992,661m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x86de28d8c7344257:0xcae6b78cb386e1d3!8m2!3d32.5431045!4d-106.6125985

Comment: @OrganicMarble but not views like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZiWJ.jpg - Oh wait!! You can zoom - omg you can really zoom in in those links, nice! I was riding on this exact road years ago, saw this and snapped a photo also. I was a little squeamish about stopping though. Shhh, don't tell anybody.

Comment: @DavidHammen I'm not sure I understand - do you mean ground stations that communicate *directly to ISS without using a relay satellite* are in Russia?